# How do I get the ClassLoaders?

Tags: java, android, classloader

What are the ClassLoaders for the following classes?

```
ArrayList<Long>

Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>>

int[]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking how to get hold of the classloaders for those classes at runtime:

```
ArrayList.class.getClassLoader()
Map.class.getClassLoader()
int[].class.getClassLoader()
```

Note that the type parameters are erased, so they are not relevant as far as the classloader is concerned.  But the Java syntax for a `class` literal requires a *`TypeIdentifier`* so you can't write this:

```
ArrayList<Long>.class.getClassLoader() // SYNTAX ERROR
```

Finally note that if the classloader for the respective classes is the bootstrap classloader, then the `getClassloader()` call *may* return `null`.